# AJAX File Upload with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, carrierwave

I have a form, with an upload field, that is displayed in a modal box and when I submit it, the errors are shown without closing this modal, but when an error occurs and there is a file already uploaded in the file field the request is processed in HTML instead of JavaScript. Does anyone know what can I do to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: You cannot upload files via AJAX. You will need to use an iframe work around or use a modern JavaScript approach using FileReader to read the file and then submit the data with the form. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. I'd recommend making your app work without AJAX first, and then add in the AJAX features as a progressive enhancement.

Comment: everything works fine in case of success? you using iframe or jqueyr-ajax file upload plugin ?

Comment: Everything works fine if there is no errors or if the errors exist but I haven't yet choosed any file. I'm studying what Ogz said, but I don't understand how can the iframe help in this case...

Answer (score 0):

application_controller.rb

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request? #add this line to json request
```

your_action.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @object, :html => {:multipart => true}, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :file%>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

your_object_controller

```
@object = Object.new(object_params)

respond_to do |format|
    if @object.save
        format.js
    end
end
```

your_action.js.erb

```
<% if remotipart_submitted? %>
    alert('submitted via remotipart');
<% else %>
    alert('submitted via native jquery-ujs');
<% end %>
```

for more documentation, visit https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart